# ¿Cómo mostrar el progreso de un ProgressBar en Winforms haciendo uso de delegados?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, hilos, progressbar

He puesto un progressBar en un formulario de Winforms, pero hasta el momento no sé como utilizarlo bien.

Inicialmente hice esto

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    //Líneas de código
    private void BtnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Líneas de código
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            pbLoading.Value = i;
            pbLoading.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(250));
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido al Sistema.", "PIED PIPER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    //Líneas de código
}
```

Sin embargo después de buscar información descubrí que no es una buena idea actulizar una barra de progreso en la forma principal pues esto genera que la interfaz de usuario pueda bloquearse, lo cual sucede en mi caso ya que mientras la barra de progreso se muestra no puedo minimizar la ventana.

Buscando más información, encontré que una manera de trabajar con barras de progreso es hacer uso de `Threads` (hilos). Investigando en SO llegué a la siguiente [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923512/threading-does-c-sharp-have-an-equivalent-of-the-java-runnable-interface). Ahí indican que lo analogo a la interface `Runnable` de Java es hacer uso de los delegados `ThreadStart` o `ParametrizedThreadStart`.

En Java hice lo siguiente:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
      @Override
      public void run()
      {  
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                pbLoading.setValue(i);
                pbLoading.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(100));
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }        
      }
}).start();
```

Mi problema radica en que no sé como "traducir" el código Java mostrado a C# haciendo uso de delegados.

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas y/o comentarios.

Comment: En .net, desde la versión 4.5, ya no se recomiendan esos métodos, utiliza métodos asíncronos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es hacer el método que te va a modificar en si el progress bar, con su delegado:

```c#
delegate void RefreshProgressDelegate(decimal percent);
public void RefreshProgress(decimal value)
{
    if (this == null) return;
    progressBar.Value = (int)value;
}
```

después ya ves tu donde llamas al delegado, pero tienes que llamarlo, mas o menos así:

```c#
private void ModificarProgressBar()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= valueUpDown.Value; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        var percent = (i / valueUpDown.Value) * 100;
        this.Invoke(new RefreshProgressDelegate(RefreshProgress), percent);
    }
    currentThread = null;
}
```